# Abrir calendario daterangepicker pelo icon

Tags: javascript, data

Gostaria de abrir esse calendário abaixo ao clicar no ícone, porém o valor deve ir para o meu `input`.

```js
var date = new Date();
var primeiroDia = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toLocaleDateString();
alert(primeiroDia)
var ultimoDia = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);



$('#date').daterangepicker({
  "singleDatePicker": true,
  "autoApply": true,
  "locale": {
    "format": "DD-MM-YYYY",
    "separator": " / ",
    "applyLabel": "Apply",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
    "fromLabel": "From",
    "toLabel": "To",
    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "weekLabel": "W",
    "daysOfWeek": [
      "Su",
      "Mo",
      "Tu",
      "We",
      "Th",
      "Fr",
      "Sa"
    ],
    "monthNames": [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ],
    "firstDay": 1,
  },
  "minDate": primeiroDia,
  "maxDate": ultimoDia

}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon" id="date">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control start_date" data-inputmask="'alias':'mm/dd/yyyy'" data-mask="" value="">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hto01c3g/5/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara pega o que está no `console.log` e transforma em uma variável, depois coloca essa variável como `.value` do `input`, não tem mistério...

[image: ódigo da imagem acima:]

Segue código da imagem acima, deixei comentado no Script onde mexi.

```js
var date = new Date();
var primeiroDia = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toLocaleDateString();
alert(primeiroDia)
var ultimoDia = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);



$('#date').daterangepicker({
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "autoApply": true,
    "locale": {
        "format": "DD-MM-YYYY",
        "separator": " / ",
        "applyLabel": "Apply",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
        "fromLabel": "From",
        "toLabel": "To",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
        "weekLabel": "W",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Su",
            "Mo",
            "Tu",
            "We",
            "Th",
            "Fr",
            "Sa"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1,
    },
    "minDate": primeiroDia,
    "maxDate": ultimoDia

}, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
    
//aqui que eu pego o que está no console.log e incluo com valor no input
let x = 'New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')';
    let y = document.querySelector('input');
    y.value = x;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon" id="date">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control start_date" data-inputmask="'alias':'mm/dd/yyyy'" data-mask="" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Bom dia @hugocsl, como eu poderia captar o dia atual sem precisar clicar no form ?

Comment: @DiêgoCorreiadeAndrade olha se isso te ajuda, esse script já pega a data atual e coloca dentro do input https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/NWKEONr aqui tem mais várias opções de como pegar a data atual https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript/

Comment: Isso conseguir fazer, porem quando eu clico no incon pra alterar a data ele permanece a setada do dia atual

Comment: @DiêgoCorreiadeAndrade acredito que é pq primeiro vc tem que limpar o input antes de colocar a data nova, no evento que vc clica no ícone, atualizei o código lá da uma olhada, quando vc clicar no body, ele vai colocar outro valor no input https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/NWKEONr